# node.js - express.static and facebook-wrapper - Cannot POST

Tags: facebook, node.js, post

I am working on a node.js project and I need to do a connection with facebook.
I picked some facebook libraries. The last one that I liked was [facebook-wrapper](https://github.com/vladbagrin/facebook-wrapper). Their example works perfect, but when I add `express.static(__dirname + '/public')`, I get an error: `Cannot POST /`. I tried with [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) too, but I have the same error.

```
var server = express.createServer( 
  express.logger(), 
  express.bodyParser(), 
  express.cookieParser(), 
  express.session({ secret: 'secret123' }), 
  facebook.auth(options), 
  express.static(__dirname + '/public')
);
```

Comment: You need to show some code. It's possible that you're putting `express.static` in the wrong place in the middleware stack, but without seeing code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: var server = express.createServer(
    express.logger(),
    express.bodyParser(),
    express.cookieParser(),
    express.session({ secret: 'secret123' }),
    facebook.auth(options),
    express.static(__dirname + '/public')
);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the static middleware doesn't serve requests coming with POST method. You have to handle it in router explicitly, like this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

However there is a pull request to ease this: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/pull/482.

Answer (score 0):

Order of arguments matters for Connet and Express. Rearrange the arguments. Try putting 'facebook.auth(options)' as last argument.